# xpath not returning text if p tag is followed by any other tag

Tags: php, xpath

i want to get all the text between `<p>` and `<h3>` tag for the following HTML

```
<div class="bodyText">
  <p>
    <div class="articleBox articleSmallHorizontal channel-32333770 articleBoxBordered alignRight">
  <div class="one">
  <a  href="url" class="img"><img src="url" alt="bar" class="img" width="80" height="60" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    <h4 class="preTitle">QIEZ-Lieblinge</h4>
    <h3 class="title"><a  href="url"  title="ABC"  onclick="cmsTracking.trackClickOut({element:this,  channel : 32333770, channelname : 'top_listen',  content : 14832081,  callTemplate : '_htmltagging.Text',  action : 'click',  mouseevent : event});">
        Prominente Gastronomen      </a></h3>
    <span class="postTitle"></span>
    <span class="district"><a href="http://www.qiez.de/berlin/top-listen" title="TOP-LISTEN in Berlin">Berlin</a></span>  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
I want this TEXT</p>
<h3>I want this TEXT</h3>
<p>I want this TEXT</p>
<p>
    <div class="inlineImage alignLeft">
  <div class="medium">
    <img src="http://images03.qiez.de/Restaurant+%C3%96_QIEZ.jpg/280x210/0/167.231.886/167.231.798" width="280" height="210" alt="Schöne Lage: das Restaurant Ø. (c)QIEZ"/>
    <span class="caption">
      Schöne Lage: das Restaurant Ø. (c)QIEZ    </span>
  </div>
</div>I want this TEXT</p>
<p>I want this TEXT</p>
<p>I want this TEXT<br /> </p>
<blockquote><img src="url" alt="" width="68" height="68" />
    "Eigentlich nur drei Worte: Ich komme wieder."<span class="author">Tina Gerstung</span></blockquote>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

i want all "I want this TEXT". i used xpath query

```
//div[contains(@class,'bodyText')]/*[local-name()='p' or local-name()='h3']
```

but it does not give me the text if `<p>` tag is followed by any other tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have div elements contained within your p element which is not valid and messing up things. If you use a var_dump in the loop you can see that it does actually pick up the node but the nodeValue is empty.

A quick and dirty fix to your html would be to wrap the first div that is contained in the p element in a span.

```
<span><div class="articleBox articleSmallHorizontal channel-32333770 articleBoxBordered alignRight">...</div></span>
```

A better fix would be to put the div element outside the paragraph.

If you use the dirty workaround you will need to change your query like so:

```
$xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'bodyText')]/*[local-name()='p' or local-name()='h3']/text()");
```

If you do not have control of the source html. You can make a copy of the html and remove the offending divs:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'articleBox')]");
$node = $nodes->item(0);
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

It might be easier to work with simple_html_dom. Maybe you can try this:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($html);

foreach($dom->find("div[class=bodyText]") as $parent) {
    foreach($parent->children() as $child) {
        if ($child->tag == 'p' || $child->tag == 'h3') {
            // remove the inner text of divs contained within a p element
            foreach($dom->find('div') as $e) 
                $e->innertext = '';
            echo $child->plaintext . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot modify the html since it is an external source.

Comment: I added some ideas about what to do if you don't have control of the source.

Answer (score 0):

This is mixed content. Depending on what defines the position of the element, you can use a number of factors. In this cse, probably simply selected all the text nodes will be sufficient:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'bodyText')]/(p | h3)/text()
```

If the union operator within a path location is not allowed in your processor, then you can use your syntax as before or a little bit simpler in my opinion:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'bodyText')]/*[local-name() = ('p', 'h3')]/text()
```

Comment: I am getting this error with both the expressions:-
Warning Error: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Comment: Seems like your XPath processor is either not standard-compliant or you have to invoke it differently. You might want to edit your question and add the relevant PHP code.